# How can I use Rollup to bundle my Angular Component created by Angular CLI in VS Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli, rollupjs

When I create a tree component in Angular by **Angular CLI**, I want to share my component to the internet. But I do not know how to bundle my component using **Rollup**, even through I bundle it in another way. What I ask is: can anybody tell me  how to fastly and correctly bundle my angular component by Rollup one step by one step. I already search the internet and try them but not work.
Here is my working Environment configuration:
**Angular CLI: 1.7.4**
**Node: 8.9.0**
**OS: win32 x64**
**Angular: 5.2.11**

Comment: What's your angular version?

Comment: At now, I bundle my angular component by **ng-packagr**, refs the guid:[example](https://github.com/jasonaden/angular-cli-lib-example).I can not find analogous and valid guids from **Rollup**. Only some posts for JavaScript.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unICbsPGFIA&t=1427s)  and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4YMmwxGKjY&t=262s)